# How to move imageview in Jbox2d like in simple code setTranslationX(); getTranslationY type Movement

Tags: java, android-studio, physics, jbox2d, sketchware

How to move imageview or any other view in jbox2d library used from jawnypoo PhysicsLayout a custom library from jbox2d I want to move objects views left right and up down I don't know how to do so please tell me how can I move object using this library I have Tried Using ApplyForceTocenter And ApplyLinearImpulse but it is not defined in it how can I get it please help me.....

LinearImpulse and applyForceToCenter was not working as it said it is not defined in library